# Microsoft coding style question

Tags: c#, coding-style

I had to figure out a way to ask this that wasn't subjective, so this is specifically for Microsoft's coding style.  In the ASP.NET MVC source, code files look like this:

```
// Copyright info

namespace System.Web.Mvc {
    using System;

    // blah blah
    // ...
}
```

Note that 'using System' lines up nicely with the namespace.  If I was to apply this style to my company's code, should I put 'using' statements for my company's namespaces directly below as well (so that it lines up)?  When I put 'using' declarations at the top, I usually start with .NET namespaces first, so that's why I'm unsure. For example, should I do this:

```
namespace MyCompany.MyProduct.Something {
    using System;
    using MyCompany.MyProduct.SomethingElse;
}
```

or this:

```
namespace MyCompany.MyProduct.Something {
    using MyCompany.MyProduct.SomethingElse;
    using System; 
}
```

I'm tempted toward the latter.

Comment: Is this really a big decision?  I mean...really?

Comment: It is if your team is going to be singing off of the same coding standard hymn sheet.

Comment: How so? If you want your team to follow the same coding standard, then it is *a* decision, but is it a big one? Why not just pick one or the other and say 'this is how we're going to do it'?

Comment: The "hymn sheet" analogy seems quite apposite. Your team may as well be singing camp fire songs to each other for all the good this is going to do them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no single Microsoft style, although there have been attempts to consolidate their standardizations.

That being said, [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) forces all System namespaces to be listed first...

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft StyleCop dictates using System.* first then your custom library namespace (i.e. the first option).

Answer (score 0):

You've got two things going on here.

1. **Alignment** - They aren't lining up anything.  They're using 4 space indents (the default)
2. **Order of using statements** - Typically you will find the system namespaces first.  Under that you will find a hierarchy of levels:

   ```
   using System;  
   using System.Collections;  
   using System.Collections.Specialized;
   ```

Comment: They are lined up. They use spaces, not tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The convention I follow is:

- System namespaces
- Microsoft namespeces
- Any external / third party namespaces
- Company's internal namesapces - common / core
- Company internal namespaces - local / project

Starting with wider scope towards narrower scope...